# JPEG parameter struct mismatch: library thinks size is 512, caller expects 520 in R

Tags: c, r, compilation, jpeg

When I use R to draw a plot in JPEG format, I got the following error:

```
JPEG parameter struct mismatch: library thinks size is 512, caller expects 520
*** glibc detected *** /home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00000000033c14c0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3fc4475e66]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3fc44789b3]
/lib64/libc.so.6(fclose+0x14d)[0x3fc44664cd]
/home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so(+0x6480)[0x7fd5d64f2480]
/home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R[0x48194d]
/home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R(Rf_killDevice+0x1a)[0x4819b3]
/home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/library/grDevices/libs/grDevices.so(devoff+0x90)[0x7fd5d62274ab]
/home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R[0x4833e2]
/home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R[0x4d2ddc]
/home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R(Rf_eval+0x1f3)[0x4c4652]
/home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R(Rf_applyClosure+0x68a)[0x4c5a9e]
/home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R(Rf_eval+0x87b)[0x4c4cda]
/home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R(Rf_ReplIteration+0x233)[0x5006f9]
/home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R[0x500896]
/home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R(run_Rmainloop+0x53)[0x501e98]
/home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R(Rf_mainloop+0xe)[0x501ead]
/home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R(main+0x2f)[0x4166a7]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x3fc441ed5d]
/home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R[0x416539]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0076f000 r-xp 00000000 00:19 21079652                           /home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R
0096f000-0097e000 rw-p 0036f000 00:19 21079652                           /home/user/Downloads/R-3.2.5_install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R
0097e000-00a6b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
02394000-03c98000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
3883200000-3883388000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52168222                       /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.42.1
3883388000-3883588000 ---p 00188000 08:03 52168222                       /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.42.1
3883588000-3883595000 rw-p 00188000 08:03 52168222                       /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.42.1
3883595000-3883596000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3883600000-388454b000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52168539                       /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.42.1
388454b000-388474a000 ---p 00f4b000 08:03 52168539                       /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.42.1
388474a000-388474b000 rw-p 00f4a000 08:03 52168539                       /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.42.1
3885400000-388553f000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52167430                       /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.42.1
388553f000-388573f000 ---p 0013f000 08:03 52167430                       /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.42.1
388573f000-3885750000 rw-p 0013f000 08:03 52167430                       /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.42.1
3885750000-3885752000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3fc4000000-3fc4020000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 27525557                       /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3fc421f000-3fc4220000 r--p 0001f000 08:03 27525557                       /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3fc4220000-3fc4221000 rw-p 00020000 08:03 27525557                       /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3fc4221000-3fc4222000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3fc4400000-3fc458a000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 27525558                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3fc458a000-3fc478a000 ---p 0018a000 08:03 27525558                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3fc478a000-3fc478e000 r--p 0018a000 08:03 27525558                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3fc478e000-3fc478f000 rw-p 0018e000 08:03 27525558                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3fc478f000-3fc4794000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3fc4800000-3fc4883000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 27525573                       /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3fc4883000-3fc4a82000 ---p 00083000 08:03 27525573                       /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3fc4a82000-3fc4a83000 r--p 00082000 08:03 27525573                       /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3fc4a83000-3fc4a84000 rw-p 00083000 08:03 27525573                       /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3fc4c00000-3fc4c02000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 27525564                       /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3fc4c02000-3fc4e02000 ---p 00002000 08:03 27525564                       /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3fc4e02000-3fc4e03000 r--p 00002000 08:03 27525564                       /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3fc4e03000-3fc4e04000 rw-p 00003000 08:03 27525564                       /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3fc5000000-3fc5017000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 27525559                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3fc5017000-3fc5217000 ---p 00017000 08:03 27525559                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3fc5217000-3fc5218000 r--p 00017000 08:03 27525559                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3fc5218000-3fc5219000 rw-p 00018000 08:03 27525559                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3fc5219000-3fc521d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3fc5400000-3fc5407000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 27525560                       /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3fc5407000-3fc5606000 ---p 00007000 08:03 27525560                       /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3fc5606000-3fc5607000 r--p 00006000 08:03 27525560                       /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3fc5607000-3fc5608000 rw-p 00007000 08:03 27525560                       /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3fc5800000-3fc5815000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 27525567                       /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3fc5815000-3fc5a14000 ---p 00015000 08:03 27525567                       /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3fc5a14000-3fc5a15000 r--p 00014000 08:03 27525567                       /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3fc5a15000-3fc5a16000 rw-p 00015000 08:03 27525567                       /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3fc6000000-3fc6115000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 27525561                       /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8
3fc6115000-3fc6315000 ---p 00115000 08:03 27525561                       /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8
3fc6315000-3fc6316000 rw-p 00115000 08:03 27525561                       /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8
3fc6316000-3fc6317000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3fc6800000-3fc6804000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 27525562                       /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0.2800.8
3fc6804000-3fc6a03000 ---p 00004000 08:03 27525562                       /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0.2800.8
3fc6a03000-3fc6a04000 rw-p 00003000 08:03 27525562                       /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0.2800.8
3fc6c00000-3fc6c4a000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 27525563                       /lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.2800.8
3fc6c4a000-3fc6e49000 ---p 0004a000 08:03 27525563                       /lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.2800.8
Aborted
```

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925171/jpeg-parameter-struct-mismatch) pointed out that it could be caused by two versions of libjpeg, but how to fix the issue? I re-installed R but still could not make it work.

Comment: Did your R reinstallation involve building it from source?  If the problem is a library incompatibility (which is only a conjecture) then reinstalling the same binary will not solve it, and installing a new pre-built binary is not guaranteed to solve it.  Building from source is far more likely to resolve such a problem, though few things in life are sure.

Comment: Hi @JohnBollinger I did rebuild the executables from source, and didn't spot any issue during compilation.

Comment: It is conceivable that the libjpeg headers against which you compiled are not the correct ones for your actual libjpeg.  That might happen because you have multiple sets of headers or the wrong headers installed, or it might happen if R provides its own headers (and maybe its own libjpeg, too).