# jpeg_decompress_struct Struct size mismatch

Tags: c++, c, struct, decode, libjpeg

I am trying to use [libJPEG](http://www.ijg.org/) version 9b on Visual Studio Community 2017 to decode an encoded image buffer (I have this from openCV).

I have followed [this example](https://gist.github.com/PhirePhly/3080633) and have written my own function which calls `jpeg_create_decompress` with the pointer to `jpeg_decompress_struct` as an argument.

My function always exits at

```
if (structsize != SIZEOF(struct jpeg_decompress_struct))
    ERREXIT2(cinfo, JERR_BAD_STRUCT_SIZE, 
         (int) SIZEOF(struct jpeg_decompress_struct), (int) structsize);
```

in the `jpeg_CreateDecompress (j_decompress_ptr cinfo, int version, size_t structsize)` method in jdapimin.c.

I have written different codes and just tried different examples available online and have run into the same issue.

```
Mat readFile = imread("ottawa.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
cout << "Read Matrix size: " << readFile.size() << endl;

vector<uchar> encodedBuffer;          // output buffer to store compressed image
vector<int> compression_params;

int jpegqual = ENCODE_QUALITY; // Compression Parameter
compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
compression_params.push_back(jpegqual);

imencode(".jpg", readFile, encodedBuffer, compression_params);       // compress the image

cout << "Encoding with OpenCV complete..." << endl;

int matSize = encodedBuffer.size();

cout << "Size of matrix: " << matSize << endl;

// Variables for the decompressor itself
struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;

unsigned long jpg_size = encodedBuffer.size();
unsigned char *jpg_buffer = &encodedBuffer.front();

cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
cout << endl << "In decode function:" << endl;
cout << "cinfo size: " << sizeof(cinfo) << endl;
cout << "jpeg_decompress_struct size: " << sizeof(struct jpeg_decompress_struct) << endl;
jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
```

I am printing the sizes of the structs in both the caller (main) and the `jpeg_CreateDecompress` function.

In the jdapimin.c file:

```
printf("\nIn jdapimin.c:\n");
printf("Structsize: %zd\n", structsize);
printf("jpeg_decompress_struct: %zd\n", sizeof(struct jpeg_decompress_struct));
```

This is the output:
[image: Output]

This is entirely my problem. I cannot understand how it is possible that the **same sizeof function returns different values**! Why is there a difference of 32? I have tried casting to size_t, removing the casting. I don't even have a remotest idea where this could be going wrong.

I am sorry for the long post, and would really appreciate any leads. Thanks!

EDIT: I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925171/jpeg-parameter-struct-mismatch?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I had compiled the library myself and linked the .lib in Visual Studio. So not sure, how to check if multiple libJPEGs are installed.

Comment: where did you assigned value to structsize?

Comment: I don't, it is done in jpeglib.h `#define jpeg_create_decompress(cinfo) \
    jpeg_CreateDecompress((cinfo), JPEG_LIB_VERSION, \
     (size_t) sizeof(struct jpeg_decompress_struct))
EXTERN(void) jpeg_CreateCompress JPP((j_compress_ptr cinfo,
          int version, size_t structsize));
EXTERN(void) jpeg_CreateDecompress JPP((j_decompress_ptr cinfo,
     int version, size_t structsize));`

Comment: But structsize comes equal in both cases at 664, so that is getting passed correctly I assume. `sizeof(struct jpeg_decompress_struct)` is giving different values. But at this point, I am not sure of anything that is happening!

Comment: `%zd` ---> `%zu`

Comment: @LPs thanks but did not work, still the same 664 and 632 output.

Comment: Are you sure that lib and application are compiled for the same arch? I mean x86 on both cases or x64 on both? If not struct can use different alignmenet: 4 instead of 8 and vice versa.

Comment: Yes I double checked that. Both are Release x64 configuration. Just now I checked whether my linking was to the correct x64 Release jpeg.lib and yes it was.

Comment: I saw some define that defines size of buffer in `jpeglib.h` Are you sure that `.h` pointed by lib project is the same with same numbers as the one used by the application project?

Comment: You are right! I opened the jpeglib.h included in both, and the locations are different. There was one more copy in my project directory itself. Now everything equals 632.
Thank you so so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

I opened the `jpeglib.h` in both my files and checked the locations. The `jpeglib.h` file that was included in `jdapimin.c` and in my program was at different locations. There was a copy in my project directory which my program was using. I deleted those `.h` files, and both were now using the one in my include directory path. This solved the problem and all values were now 632.

Thanks to @LPs' suggestions in the comments.